# Disable basic authentication for specific end point, and keep all other secured

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-rest

Right now I configure web security adapter like -

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .fullyAuthenticated().and()
            .httpBasic().and()
            .csrf()
            .disable();
 }
}
```

Which working fine and blocking all requests if not authenticated. But now I want to block all but `/login`. I mean, I want JUST `/login` and `/login/*` to be insecure, and rest of the app to be secured.

Anyone knows how can I achieve that?

Comment: Configure it like that. Add a security rule which allows full access to those urls.

Comment: @M.Deinum: that is what i am looking for, i mean how the configuration should be.

Comment: Something like `authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "/login/*).permitAll()`. All of that is explained in the reference guide.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the /login url to ignore list in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception{
        webSecurity
            .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/login");
    }
}
```